# Real Analysis Inequalities

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

I am taking an introduction to real analysis course and I am struggling to prove the folowing inequalities. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Deduce the following statements:

(i) $e^{x}\ge ex$, for all $x$,

(ii) $\log x\le x-1$, for all $x>0$,

(iii) $e^{y}\ge y^{e}$, for all $y>0$.

Answer (score 2):

i)
That this holds for $x<0$ is clear since $e^x$ is positive for any $x$. Then for $x\geq 0$, we examine
$$
f(x)=e^x-ex
$$
$f(0)=1$ and $f'(x)=e^x-e$, and by examining both sides of $x=1$ with precalculus tools, it follows that $f$ decreases from 1 to $0=f(1)$ on the interval $[0,1]$ and increases for $x>1$, allowing us to conclude that we never have $e^x<ex$.

ii)
Take the exponential of both sides of the expression $\log x+1\sim x$ and use part $i$

iii)
Take the log of both sides and use part $i$.

Comment: Aptly done.  +1.